# Why disorder my views in cell of table view when swipe a cell?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I am setting up swipe action for a cell of a table view. When I swipe cell views in this cell became a disorder and I checked the constraint of label Views and imageView.

this is a gif image of my problem:
https://ibb.co/SwwfYMB

this is a ​photo of my constraint of cell
[my constraint of cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NWCr.png)

This is my code

```
 // MARK: delete Action
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let itemREF = arrayItems[indexPath.row].itemId
        let imageREF = arrayItems[indexPath.row].Image

        let storage = Storage.storage()
        let storageRef = storage.reference(forURL: imageREF!)
        storageRef.delete { error in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            } else {
                // File deleted successfully
            }
        }

        Database.database().reference().child("Items").child(itemREF!).removeValue()

        arrayItems.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        let deleteIndex = [indexPath]
        tableView.deleteRows(at: deleteIndex, with: .automatic)
//        self.myTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        self.myTableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: Maybe unrelated but **never** call `reloadData()` right after `insert/deleteRows(`.  `insert/deleteRows(` does update the UI and you throw away the nice animation.

Comment: This is very unlikely to have anything to do with the code that you showed. Have you any evidence that the code even runs? Seems more likely that you've got ambiguous constraints. Use the View Debugger to track that down.

Comment: @matt thank you Matt, i will try!

Answer (score 0):

```
it seems that problem with you image view you can use UIStackview like 
<UIStackView>
<orientation>horizontal>
<FirstView/>
<ImageView>
</UIStackView>
this is for example how stackview will manage also set constraints accordingly leading and trailing.
```

Comment: I did like this but same !

Comment: @Fahadlqbal i added the photo of the constraint of the cell!